# Search through a content of List<String> using Regex

Tags: regex, dart

I know we can check individual items of a List and match it against a regex. I wanted to know if there was a function that would check all the contents of a list for a regex match and let me know if any of the items in a list match a regex.
For example suppose I have  a string like this

```
List<String> lst = ["Carfax","Carmax","Carpro","VanPro"];
```

I would like to know if any of the items in the list contain the word car

Comment: A concrete example that demonstrates what you try to accomplish with example data, regexp pattern and expected result would improve the quality of your question a lot.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear - I just updated my question incase other people might need a quick resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void main() {
  List<String> lst = ["Carfax","Carmax","Carpro","VanPro"];
  var regExp = new RegExp('car', caseSensitive: false);
  var result = lst.where((item) => regExp.hasMatch(item)).toList();
  print(result);
}
```

If the RegExp is so simple you can also just use `contains`, but I assume the simple regexp from the question was just for brevity of the example.

```
void main() {
  List<String> lst = ["Carfax", "Carmax", "Carpro", "VanPro"];
  var result = lst.where((item) => item.toLowerCase().contains('car')).toList();
  print(result);
}
```

Comment: I havent tested this yet - So if I wanted to know if there were matching items i can simply check the size of result ?

Comment: I updated my answer according to your updated question. Yes, the `result` contains the items from `lst` that match the regexp pattern and the length is the number of matching items. If you don't care about the number of matches, you can use `any` instead of where and get `true` or `false` as result. This is more efficient, because any only looks for the first match and then returns while `where` checks all items to the end even when it already found a match.

Comment: That was a very informative answer , specially for people starting with Dart. I hate it when people downvote without giving a reason. Upvoting

Comment: @Rajeshwar yup, and if it was for a legit reason it prevents others learning about that reasoning.